# How to find an element with multiple class names using Xpath or CssSelector

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to access this element:

```
div data-v-658f4ceb="" class="trn-gamereport-list trn-gamereport-list--compact">
```

I know that since it has multiple names in the class I would need to use either the XPath or CSS selector method to access it but whenever I try either of these codes:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
driver.get(url)
crucible_content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'trn-gamereport-list') and contains(@class, 'trn-gamereport-list--compact')]")
crucible_content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")
```

I get this error:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class, 'trn-gamereport-list') and contains(@class, 'trn-gamereport-list--compact')]"}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me in figuring out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the html part from parent node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are dynamic elements, so to locate the elements within the [website](https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible")
  crucible_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible")  
  crucible_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='trn-gamereport-list trn-gamereport-list--compact']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: would i need to do this for every element that I want to access?

Comment: Would vary from usecase to usecase. See the embedded links for granular details.